# Run Tomcat in another server

Tags: jsp, tomcat, containers

I think this question can be kinda idiot, but anyway: I'm working in a site and only have access to the ftp login and password. The site is already uploaded and working, but it's php. I wanna do a CMS using JSP, but it seems like the server doesn't run jsp.

I would like to know if there is any way to install/configure a container (like tomcat) in the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.... in theory: yes. Will you host provider allow that: probably not. Mind you it's a best guesstimate. You might have to look at some host providers that specialize in offering hosting for Tomcat, etc.